# Order of symbols in Graphics labels

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, labeling

Do you have any idea how to force an order of Greek letter in the graphics? When I type in

```
AxesLabel -> {Cost, Δ OverBar[π]}
```

the order is `π Δ`. How can I force it to be `Δ π`?

Answer (score 9):

Simply put the label in a string, i.e. between quotes.  You can still type any expression you like, including `OverBar`.  From the docs:

> OverBar[expr] can be entered using Ctrl+& and _.

Alternatively, wrap the expression in `HoldForm` or use `Row`:

```
AxesLabel -> {Cost, Row[{Δ , OverBar[π]}]}
```

Comment: Just to exhaust the topic, worth to mention about `StringForm` and `Grid`.

Comment: @Kuba Feel free to edit them in.  It's community wiki, which signals that I'm okay with it, no need to ask.