# Output with a message

Tags: output-formatting

If I have, for example,

```
z[w_] := w^2
```

and then

```
z[2]
4
```

I'd like to get

```
"at w=2 we get" 4
```

Comment: Lookup `Row` or `StringTemplate`/`StringExpression` etc. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Do those answer fit your needs? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123146/5478

Comment: Another one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43289/5478